# Saving files in a webhosting with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, filesystems, web-hosting

I have a problem with saving files (photos) with laravel in a web hosting. 
I can do it in localhost and works perfectly. But now I migrate all project to a web hosting, but  saving files is not working.

The form is working, the name of file it's saved, but the file not.

I have this code into my config/filesystems.php:

```
'local' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path('web/photos'),
],
```

And I have this folders in public_html/web/photos Whats is wrong?

Comment: Likely a permissions issue. Try a `dd(is_writable(public_path('web/photos')))` somewhere in your code to check.

Comment: Or log it. Wouldn't recommend dd'ing on live.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about file permissions, on your web webserver you need to change it.

If you have console access:

```
sudo chown www-data /public_html/web/photos
sudo chmod 755 /public_html/web/photos
```

Or by FTP-client like so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWBwqlUhQOM

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit new, and I'm a little lost. Which file I need to change it? filesystems.php?

Comment: No, you need to set permission (as on video) to any folders that you want to be uploadable, in this case `/public_html/web/photos`

Comment: It's possible to do this into cpanel?

Comment: Yeap, here's the doc: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm

Comment: Ahhh, i get your mistake, you must create folder with permission located at `/public_html/public/web/photos` not just `/public_html/web/photos`

Comment: but why I must create another folder? If I change the name "web" for "public" is the same?

Comment: Are whole your laravel code store in `public_html` and have `public` directory inside of it?

Comment: Function `public_path('web/photos')` returns you `root` path (that in your case `public_html`) + `public` + `'web/photos'`. And at the end it `/public_html/public/web/photos`.

Comment: I have all my laravel code outside of "public_html" and only files of "public" folder into "public_html/web". Maybe this is my mistake? I must have all code store into "public_html?"